# This simple piece of code gives an error when it gets looped for the second time

Tags: python, string, random

```
import random
import string



for x in range(0,15):
    print "something"
    string= str(random.choice(string.letters)+str(random.randint(100,10000))+random.choice(string.letters)+str(random.randint(0,100)))
    print  string
```

Why does this code throw an error when it runs for the second time inside the for loop? I have no idea how it works perfectly for the first time and throws this error:

> something J6554r15 something
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\test\Desktop\soooo.py", line 8, in 
>       string= str(random.choice(string.letters)+str(random.randint(100,10000))+ran
>   dom.choice(string.letters)+str(random.randint(0,100))) AttributeError:
>   'str' object has no attribute 'letters'

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're using the name `string` for your result which replaces the `string` module you imported. Rename your variable.

Comment: shadow variable names! `string` library with `string` variable.

Comment: BTW, you don't need that outer `str` call, the stuff you're converting is already a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the variable `string` inside the loop which overwrites the `import string` library. Hence, on the second round you no longer have the string library to use `string.letters` but an actual string. Try using a different variable name.